# Pass JS value to PHP using POST(without submit and refresh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I have google map in my website which is updating geocoordinats when dragging marker and shows address. JS passing values of X and Y to html "ID". I can send data by "GET", but I need to pass these values using POST and get in in another page to do INSERT command. Please help anyone, stucked 4 days in same thing.

P.S. header is busy and i need wihtout submit, cause it is already in FORM with submit button.

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = [
latLng.lat()
    
  ];

}
function updateMarkerPositions(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('y').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lng()
  ];

}



function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.010299474408573, 153.39518896484606);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
    updateMarkerPositions(marker.getPosition());
 

 var js_var= marker.getPosition(); 
    document.getElementById("link").onclick = function () {   
   // ajax start
   var xhr;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers 
   else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE
   
   var url = 'process.php?js_var=' + js_var;
   type: 'POST';
   xhr.open('POST', url, false);
   
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
     var div = document.getElementById('infos');
     div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
   }
   xhr.send();
   // ajax stop
   return false;
  }
 

  
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#mapCanvas {
    width: 97%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcxTuiDebbsXYlEFomC1VEhvzD7_nB7Nc&sensor=false"></script>

<pre><div><div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
   <b>Ünvan:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
 <button href="#" id="link">Address accept</button>
      <div  id="x" ></div>
      <div  id="y" ></div>
      <div id="infos" ></div>
      <div id="markerStatus" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div></pre>
```

I use second "PHP" code to get "$_GET" data.

```html
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['js_var'])) 
 {

 $php_var = $_GET['js_var'];

 $subaftercomme= substr($php_var, 0, strpos($php_var, ','));
 $getX = substr($subaftercomme, 1);
 echo "<input value=\"$getX\" disabled=\"disabled\" />";
 $subfromcomma = substr($php_var, strpos($php_var, ",") + 1);
 $getY = substr($subfromcomma, 1, -1);
 echo "<input value=\"$getY\" disabled=\"disabled\" />";
 echo "<button type=\"hidden\"  name=\"badu\" value=\" Testiqle\" >hello</button>";
 }
 else
 {
   $php_var = "<br />js_var is not set!";
   echo $php_var;
 }
?>
```

Comment: sounds like you just need AJAX

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried uje AJAX, but all my codes crashed and could not send data using POST. May be you know working code for my case?

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov What do you mean by `crashed`? What is the error?

Comment: was it jquery's ajax?

Comment: I do not know the error exactly, i tried to send value from index.php and get it in process.php(file where i send js value). in process.php i wrote `if (isset($_POST('my_data'))) ` and it told me that did not isset.
I deleted that ajax code, cause it was not working and stucked totally.. **P.S.** `crushed` - i mean was not working

Comment: give us the ajax code that you tried, otherwise we're of no help

Comment: ok, i will write ajax code again and post it here.

Comment: In you posted code there is ajax code may be you are not getting it.see the button accept address and click on it. if you have `process.php` then it should post the data there.

Comment: if you're using jquery, why don't you just use jquery's ajax?

Comment: and what's with the line `type: 'POST';`

Comment: @A.Lau ir is wrong, not complated code, i deleted it. I tried use many things, but i do smth wrong and codes not working, now i am trying to write new ajax to send data.

Comment: @Suchit yes, i am not getting it. I am gettin "GET" , but I need "POST"

Comment: when you pass value in url `'process.php?js_var=' + js_var` you receive it through $_GET.

Comment: @Suchit yes, you can see it in second file i posted. `if (isset($_GET['js_var'])) 
 {....`

Comment: read this post:https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.  you can use formdata to send the data with post.

Comment: @Suchit it was right way, thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the request header for the `POST` request:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: Unfortunately,this code bellow does not help.
`xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Comment: What do you do transmit with the `xhr.send`? Try something like `xhr.send("js_var="+js_var)` or `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(js_var))`

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me!) I am totally forgot about send)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you tagged this question with jQuery I'm going to use jquery (as I'm more familiar with it).

```
$.post("process.php",
  {
    "js_var": js_var
  },
  function(data, status)
  {
    var div = document.getElementById('infos');
    div.innerHTML = data;
    // not sure what your data returns but you might need to change it
  }
);
```

For more information click [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thank you for help and reply, this one is also working , but need to change!)